# Autowiring Map from Spring applicationContext into JSF bean

Tags: spring, jsf, autowired

I have JSF 2.0 + Spring project and there are going on some strange things when I try to autowiring Spring bean into JSF bean. Here is sample of my applicationContext:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ticketfront" />

<util:map id="map" > 
    <entry key="rp">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="9003" value="RegP"/>
        </util:map>
    </entry>
</util:map>
```

Here is part of my jSF bean:

```
@Named
@Scope("session")
public class TicketViewBean implements Serializable {

@Autowired
Map<String, Map<String, String>> map;
}
```

Deployment run successful but in my jsf bean autowired property map first entry is normal like I configured in applicationContext but there are a lot of other entry's that are put into map. For example:

```
map = (java.util.LinkedHashMap) {map={rp={9003=RegP}}, systemEnvironment={USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Administrator, JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40, NB_EXEC_TOMCAT_START_PROCESS_UUID=tomcat70:home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.34:base=apache-tomcat-7.0.34.0_base, SystemDrive=C:, JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_shmem, CURRENT_DIR=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Ap
```

And many other different stuff, even WEB-XML....

I am totally confused why this happens

Comment: You are running into a corner case the `Map<String, ?>` is a bit of a special case as it will give you all beans with the name (as key) and the value). You are basically requesting all `Map` typed beans, which is also what you see. The first entry isn't as you say but it is actually your map with the elements and not the single element `rp`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation) in the Spring Reference guide

> Even typed Maps can be autowired as long as the expected key type is `String`. The `Map` values will **contain all beans of the expected type**, and the keys **will contain the corresponding bean names**:

So what you get is a `Map` of `Map`s. Which will give you your own `Map` but also all other beans that can be expressed as a `Map` or which are a `Map`. This is the case for most `PropertySource` beans, which you get in your `Map` in the bean. (The `systemEnvironment` are all the environment variables) and so on.

To fix add a `@Qualifier("map")` to your definition or use `@Resource` instead of `@Autowired`.